# How to get the Header and Footer after the login succesfull

Tags: angular

In my app component I have **Header** and **footer** directives and in between i have **router outlet** to render all other components.

**App.Component.html:**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**App.Component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    title = 'Smart Shopping';
```

}

initially i am rendering my login Component when application starts.

**Login.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  credentials = { username: '', password: '' };

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private service: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.service.login(this.credentials.username, this.credentials.password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      )

  }
}
```

on Login Button I am going to load the **Home Component**

on this step i want my header and footer visible . i want that users can see the header and footer only if they logged in.

I can do this by giving directives of header and footer in Home component but by doing this I have to give the directives in all other components to get header and footer which is not a good approach approach . how can i my desire output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use like this 
make an wrapper component for example 
**wrappercomponent**

```
 <app-header></app-header>
<ng-content></ng-content>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and where you want your header and footer to visible for example if you want in your home component so in html of home component use wrapper directives like

```
<wrapper>
home component here
</wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *ngIf with footer and header like this

```
<app-header *ngIf="loggedIn"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="loggedIn"></app-footer>
```

Then add loggedIn property to class

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  credentials = { username: '', password: '' };
  loggedIn = false;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private service: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.service.login(this.credentials.username, this.credentials.password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.loggedIn = true;
          console.log(data);
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        },
        err => {
          this.loggedIn = false;
          console.log(err);
        }
      )

  }
}
```